# JQuery append to dynamic div elements - async script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been using JQuery to append objects to divides. However I need to clear a section of the screen completely and append html to newly created layout.

```
 <div class="main"><div class="example"></div></div>

  $('.example').append('some code');
```

Works fine, however

```
<div class="main"></div>
 $('.main').append('<div class="example"></div>');
 $('.example').append('some code');
```

Does not generate anything on screen.

Edit:

I discovered why. I am using google maps and appending:

```
<script async="async" defer="defer" 
 src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?  
key='+map_key+'&amp;libraries=visualization&amp;callback=initialize">
```

The map loads, but I cannot use any methods relating to it (ie to add markers). The page just stops loading after the call.

Comment: please show an example of non-working code on eg. jsfiddle.net

Comment: The code you claim doesn't work works fine for me https://jsfiddle.net/tx7ucos5/. Please post a [mcve] in your question.

Comment: Which Version of jquery are you using?Btw use $('#id').html() with id selector.its just a suggestion,if you use class selector and that class used for other elements will be affected that might not be your intention.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but your example works fine.

```js
$('.main').append('<div class="example"></div>');
$('.example').append('some code');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main"></div>
```

Maybe check if your js is in the document ready block.

Comment: Thanks. It is in a document ready block. I will see if the bug is elsewhere :).